# Scapy How to get the time of sniffed packet in microsecond?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scapy

I'm using python 3.6 in OS X, trying to use scapy to sniff packets but the time of packets are always in second instead microsecond like what Wireshark did.

```
# Python 3.6, Anaconda
# OS X 10.12.2
# scapy-python3 (0.20)
from scapy.all import *

a = sniff(iface="en0", filter="tcp", count=3)
a.nsummary()
for pkt in a:
    print(pkt.time)
```

> **Result:**
>   
> 1490027124
>   
> 1490027124
>   
> 1490027124

Does anyone know how to get the time in microseconds like 1490027124.123456 ?

Comment: I tested (copy-pasted) your code and the results I got were in the format: `1490050827.69`. I use **os x 10.12.3** and **python2.7**.